# Meaning of "shook the bottom out of all my Sunday-school teachings"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does the sentence in bold mean?

> He was not heard of for a long time. At last he turned up as an apprentice engineer on a steamboat. **This thing shook the bottom out of all my Sunday-school teachings**.

([Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8tNy4wt_YAhXuSN8KHVw-BS0QFggwMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocumentslide.com%2Fdocuments%2Fchapter-4simple-literary-texts-by-hassan-rezaei.html&usg=AOvVaw1T05VP6CZeTbvv7ConrqBw): *A Young Boy's Ambition* by Mark Twain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "shook the bottom out of ..." is a variation on the modern phrase "knock the bottom out of ...", which [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/knock+the+bottom+out+of) defines as

> To undermine, weaken, or destroy something.

"[Sunday-school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday_school) teachings" refers to what is taught in religious education in Christian countries. This type of school is typically run by the church, not by the regular school system.

Together, the expression "[X] shook the bottom out of all my Sunday-school teachings" means "[X] destroyed the religious ideas or beliefs I had been taught at Sunday school".